# Changing asynchronous function to synchronous function using Pattern promise jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm trying to use the best practics with Javascript but it's so hard for me.In this case I wanna use some function "avoid" the callbacks. I'm trying to use the Deferred object of jquery to do it. So I believe that I don't how to works fine.

I'm working with **phonegap** + **emberjs** + **cordova-sqlite-plugin**.

I've the follwing function that implements callbacks.

```js
getPuntos: function(callback)
{
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Rondas", "1.0", "Dev", -1);

    var ret ={data:false};
    db.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * from Punto;",[], function(tx, res)
        {
            if( res.rows.length !== 0)
            {
                var puntos =  [];
                for( var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    var descripcion = res.rows.item(i).descripcion;
                    var id = res.rows.item(i).id;
                    //console.log( descripcion );
                    var punto = App.Punto.create( { index: i, id:id, descripcion: descripcion});
                    puntos.push( punto );
                }
                ret.data = puntos;
                callback(ret.data);
            }

        });
    },function(tx,err){
        console.log('Error SQL'+err);
    },function(){
        console.log( 'Base de datos abierta' );
    });     
}
```

and I use this as well:

```js
this.getPuntos(function(puntos){
   for( var i=0; i<puntos.length; i++){
     console.log( puntos[i] );
   }
});
```

Well, but I try to implements something very clear and easy like:

```js
//whitout use a callback.
var puntos = this.getPuntos();
for( var i=0; i<puntos.length; i++){
     console.log( puntos[i] );
}
```

Then I try to do it:

1. Change the function `getPuntos` to `_getPuntos`, this function has a deferred obeject.
2. the function `getPuntos` is wrapper to handle the result of promise getting in the method `_getPuntos` and try to return.(but not works)

```js
_getPuntos: function()
{
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Rondas", "1.0", "Dev", -1);
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();   
    var ret ={data:false};
    db.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * from Punto;",[], function(tx, res)
        {
            if( res.rows.length !== 0)
            {
                var puntos =  [];
                for( var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    var descripcion = res.rows.item(i).descripcion;
                    var id = res.rows.item(i).id;
                    //console.log( descripcion );
                    var punto = App.Punto.create( { index: i, id:id, descripcion: descripcion});
                    puntos.push( punto );
                }
                //ret.data = puntos;
                //callback(ret.data);
                deferred.resolve(puntos);
            }

        });
    },function(tx,err){
        console.log('Error SQL'+err);
    },function(){
        console.log( 'Base de datos abierta' );
    });
    return deferred.promise(); 
},
```

The wrapper:

```js
getPuntos: function()
{
    var promise  = this._getPuntos();
    var ret = {data:false};
    promise.done(function(result)
    {
        ret.data = result;
        return ret.data;
    }); 
    while(ret.data ===false ){} //wait for the result until it's available
    return ret.data;        
},
```

In the main function I call it :

```js
var puntos = this.getPuntos();
console.log( puntos+"--shoulbe [object]"); //I get Undefined or false, but no my array.
```

So, is there some way to do that I wanna, convert a asynchronous function in synchronous
function?.

Thanks for all your  answers.

Comment: No. Promises don't magically make a function synchronous (which would defeat the point of concurrency). They're just a good [abstraction over callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that your getPuntos() function in the second example does not return anything hence the null/false value.

```
getPuntos: function() 
{
    var promise  = this._getPuntos();
    var ret = {data:false};
    promise.done(function(result)
    {
         // This happens in the future
         ret.data = result;
         return ret.data;
    });    
// This happens now and there is nothing returned 
},
```

When your promise is completed (promise.done) it returns ret.data but this is returned to the promise and is ignored. It is in the wrong scope. You thinking in a traditional 'pull' model where data is pulled towards you and the program blocks until data is available. Javascript uses callbacks and is more of a 'push' model where data is pushed onto callbacks when it is available and there is no blocking.

You need to rearrange things. For example the getPuntos function should return the promise.

```
getPuntos: function() 
{
    var promise  = this._getPuntos();
    return promise;
},
```

And the main function should add a callback for when the promise is fulfilled.

```
var puntos = this.getPuntos();
puntos.done(function(result) {
    console.log( result+"--shoulbe [object]");
});
```

Although the getPuntos() function is a bit redundant here as it is just returning the value of _getPuntos().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `getPuntos()` function sets up the `promise.done` action, but the returned value never gets passed to the rest of your program.  As NoxHarmonium said, your `getPuntos()` method is superfluous and should be combined with `_getPuntos()`, but you probably want something like the following (as you can see in **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/xUDX3/))**:

```
PuntosPromise = function() {
    this.result = null;
    this._getPuntos = function() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function(scope) {
            scope.result = "It works."
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 500, this);
        return deferred.promise();
    }
    this.getPuntos = function()
    {
        var promise  = this._getPuntos();
        return promise;        
    }
    this.getResults = function() {
        return this.result;
    };
}
$("#tester").click(function() {
    var test = new PuntosPromise();
    $.when(test.getPuntos()).then(function() {
        alert(test.getResults());
    });
});
```

EDIT:

See @Bergi's modifications given below. While this code works, his solution is cleaner.

Comment: a) Don't use the name `Promise` for anything that is not a promise constructor (yours is a custom puntos-getter-whatever) b) don't use a `result` variable - just resolve the deferred!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the advice. As to (a), I would never do that in actual code; I was just writing quickly and sloppily. As to (b), could you explain why what I wrote is bad practice? I personally like the additional abstraction it gives, but that's mostly just aesthetic: I find this more readable.

Comment: It's bad practise because the deferred itself is capable of storing the result. A promise does represent a future (result) value, not the completion of a task. Please don't tell me that [this (half loc)](http://jsfiddle.net/xUDX3/1/) is less readable.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for succinctly and clearly answering my question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but the aim of the function `getPuntos` is return a single result ,no a callback, if I can do `var test= new PuntosPromise()` and then whitout nothing `var r = test.getResults()` awesome.

Comment: @CristianChaparroA. As I understand it, promises just don't work that way. Maybe something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/xUDX3/2/) would work better for you? `function getPuntos(puntosHandler) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("It works.")
    }, 500);
    deferred.promise().done(puntosHandler);
    return deferred.promise();
}

function resultHandler(resultFromPuntos) {
    alert(resultFromPuntos);
}

$("#tester").click(function() {
    getPuntos(resultHandler);
});`

Comment: I'm so wrong, it's mean that there aren't  way to convert an asynchronous function to synchronous function, thus eliminating the callback.In the better case I need to use a nested `then` from promise, like the @Bergi suggestion

Comment: @CristianChaparroA.: Yes, exactly.